# How to get woocommerce Category page in next.js frontend with query without using graphql

Tags: woocommerce, next.js

I can get the all categories name with this api but how can I extract all products of one category.

> This is nextjs frotend with wordpress backend

```
const WooCommerceRestApi = require("@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api").default;


    
const api = new WooCommerceRestApi({
url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WORDPRESS_SITE_URL,
consumerKey: process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
consumerSecret: process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET,
version: "wc/v3"
});

export default async function handler(req, res){
const responseData = {
    success:false,
    categories: []
}
const { perPage} = req?.query ?? {};
try {
    const {data} = await api.get(
        'customers',
        {
            per_page:perPage||100


        }
    );
    responseData.success = true;
    responseData.customers = data;
    res.json( responseData);
} catch ( error ){
    responseData.error = error.message;
    res.status(500).json(responseData);
}
```

Comment: In your example, you get customers, not categories..

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer easily if you make the effort to read the official WooCommerce API docs ;-)

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products

> This API helps you to view all the products.
>
> GET /wp-json/wc/v3/products?category=1
>
> Parameter | Type  | Description
> category  | string    | Limit result set to products assigned a specific category ID.

Applied to Next.js:

```
  try {
    const response = await api.get("products", { category:1 });
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I need to put it dynamic, I tried   const responseData = {
        success:false,
        category: [],
        products:[],
        $id:[]

    }


    const { perPage} = req?.query ?? {};
    try {
        const {data} = await api.get(
            "products", { category:$id },
            {
                per_page:perPage||10


            }
        );
        responseData.success = true;
        responseData.category = data;
        res.json( responseData);
    } catch ( error ){
      but didnot work

Comment: Please be way more precise: how does it not work, exactly, what happens instead, did you debug?

Comment: apart from that: `api.get( "products", { category:$id, per_page:perPage||10 } )`. and what happens, if you omit the per_page parameter?

Comment: Hi, I receive this at http://localhost:3000/api/get-category?perPage=1                  
    {
"success": true,
"category": [],
"categories": [],
"$id": []
}.   I want to extract category dynamically. Thank you  for help in advance.

Comment: so far I am able to get category by id at json formate at http://localhost:3000/api/get-category?$id=26 but how can i map it to frontend?